# jquery TimePicker interval

Tags: jquery, time, timepicker

I am having the hardest time trying to figure out how to get the drop down intervals of time picker to set to 15min intervals. Its defaulted to 30mins atm. What is the proper call/notation to get it to work? I've tried many variations of putting them in '' and without but no progress. Thanks!

```
   $(str).timepicker({
        'interval': '15',
        'timeFormat': 'g:ia',
        //stepMinute: 15
    });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wvega/A9cE6/light/ check this example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`step` is what you are looking for:

```
$(str).timepicker({
     'step': '15'
});
```

Comment: good gracious!! Thanks Britni. May I ask where you found this? I have looked through the docs and found no mention of this. Thanks again :D